# How create drop zone inside a drop zone with angular material 8 cdk drag n drop?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I am trying to create a form designer where there is a list of controls (input, textarea, etc) and dragging them to a tab which contains the form controls for designing the form. But I need to activate another drop zone inside that tab ( which is already a drop zone ). I have used **cdkDropListGroup**, **cdkDropList** and **[cdkDropListData]**.

```
<div class="row" cdkDropListGroup>

   <div cdkDropList
        [cdkDropListData]="copyControlList" 
        class="control-list mat-elevation-z1"      // control list to drag
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
   </div>


   <div cdkDropList
        [cdkDropListData]="copyControlList" 
        class="control-list mat-elevation-z1"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">            // drop zone for controls

        <div cdkDropList
           [cdkDropListData]="copyControlList"      
           class="control-list mat-elevation-z1"       // another drop zone for controls
           (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        </div>

   </div>

  /// other controls (input, textarea)


 </div>
```

I am using angular materials cdk Drag and drop

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Looks like, Nested dropzone is not possible with angular material cdk drag n drop. I had used "ngx-drag-drop" for it